# Netflify Serverless Function JSON parse error Sendgrid API

Tags: json, sendgrid, serverless, netlify

My contact form is not sending the frontend user to my thank you page neither is it sending any information to me via the Sendgrid APi. The issue comes from the fact that I'm not sure how to turn the JSON object into a string and then straight back to an Object..... Or as you can see I have a hard time even framing my question. The goal would be to send the information to my email account using Sendgrid API.

The form is live here:
https://www.metsanotus.fi/yhteydenotto

The code is based 99% off these two tutorials:

https://oliverschmidt.dev/blog/adding-a-contact-form-to-a-static-site-with-netlify-functions/

https://dev.to/char_bone/using-netlify-lambda-functions-to-send-emails-from-a-gatsbyjs-site-3pnb

The code for the contact-page:
https://gist.github.com/otsolap/f05cd4e3a1a08794f61a6d5730abc695

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { RiSendPlane2Line } from "react-icons/ri";

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query ContactQuery($id: String!){
        markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
            html
            excerpt(pruneLength: 140)
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`

const Contact = ({ data }) => {
  const { markdownRemark, site } = data // data.markdownRemark holds your post data
  const { frontmatter, html } = markdownRemark
  // input type hidden on netlifytä varten, jotta netlify tietää mikä lomake kyseessä.
  // contact on meidän lomake, niin kaikki viestit löytyy contact-lomakkeen alta.
  // honeypot=bot-field on botteja varten.
  // p hidden pitää kohdan piilossa, mutta console.logilla sen löytää. ;-)


  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    subject: '',
    message: '',
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  const handleSendEmail = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch("/.netlify/functions/contact-form-email", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formState),
      })
      if (!response.ok) {
        //EI 200 response
        return
      }
      //all OK
    } catch (event) {
      //error
    }
  }



  return (
    <Layout className="contact-page">
      <SEO
        title={frontmatter.title}
        description={frontmatter.title + " " + site.siteMetadata.title}
      />
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <div className="description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
        <form className="contact-form"
          action="/kiitos"
          name="contact"
          method="POST"
          data-netlify="true"
          value="contact"
          data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
          onSubmit={handleSendEmail}
        >
          <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
          <p hidden><input name="bot-field" /></p>
          <p>
            <label><input
              required
              placeholder="Nimi *"
              type="text"
              name="name"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            </label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label><input required
              placeholder="Sähköposti *"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            </label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label><input required
              placeholder="Puhelin *"
              type="number"
              name="phone"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            </label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label><input placeholder="Aihe"
              type="text"
              name="subject"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            </label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label><textarea
              placeholder="Viesti"
              name="message"
              onChange={handleChange}
            ></textarea></label>
          </p>
          <p className="text-align-center">
            <button className="button"
              type="submit">
              Lähetä<span className="icon -right"><RiSendPlane2Line />
              </span>
            </button>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Contact
```

The code for the serverless function:
https://gist.github.com/otsolap/e157b136aee040281f20ba87131014eb

```
require('dotenv').config();
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const {
  SENDGRID_API_KEY,
  METSAN_OTUS_NAME,
  METSAN_OTUS_ADDRESS }
  = process.env

sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY)

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  const payload = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const { email, subject, message } = payload

  const msg = {
    to: METSAN_OTUS_ADDRESS,
    name: METSAN_OTUS_NAME,
    from: email,
    subject: subject ? subject : 'Yhteydenotto lomakkeesta',
    text: message,
  };

  try {
    await sgMail.send(msg)
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: "Viesti lähetetty"
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      body: e.message,
      statusCode: 500,
    }
  }
};
```

When I keep the JSON.parse(body.event) this is the error it displays:
https://gist.github.com/otsolap/79830f6cf1e9b247c63c1f3f49c5286b

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

If I change the line  13 of serverless-function.js from  JSON.parse(event.body) to (for example)  JSON.stringify(event.body) the error becomes this:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'payload' as it is undefined.
```

So I guess my question is how should I formulate my serverless function so that the React object from UseState can become readable for my function?

Comment: What do you get if you log `event.body`?

Comment: Event.body and payload right now both provide the same result:
{"name":"test name","email":"test@gmail.com","phone":"0123540101","subject":"test 2","message":"test"}

^^ if I parse the JSOn then the console.log formats it nicely as an object but the result is still the same.

Comment: I thought you said that `const payload = JSON.parse(event.body)` caused the `SyntaxError`?

Comment: Yes. sorry for causing the confusion! Parse gives me Syntaxerror and stringify causes typeerror.

Comment: Did you try not parsing or stringifying and just loading the variables from `event.body`? Like `const { email, subject, message } = event.body`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question but how exactly would you do this?

Comment: I’m suggesting you don’t try to do anything to `event.body`, it seems like maybe it is already parsed. So just use `event.body` like a regular object?